# Changing a tab content on click using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, database, tabs, onclick

I am developing a tab based interface for my website. When user clicks a tab its data get loaded from the database using a JSP function. When he clicks the next tab its data get loaded and so on. Each time a tab is clicked the data is fetched from the database. Please suggest me any AJAX(or any other) code for this.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? What difficulties did you encounter with your code? Right now you have just posted your customer/manager/teacher requirements here. But you didn't show your progress so you cannot possibly expect that someone will write the code for you. You might hire a developer for this job.

Comment: I just want an example code for fetching database entries on clicking on tab.

Comment: So I repeat my question: What have you tried? If you cannot answer this question it is very unlikely that you will get answers. Of course you could hope someone might answer your question. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't tried anything because I know javascript is a client side technology while JSP is a server side technology. But I came to know that AJAX can do my work. But I don't know anything about AJAX. And I also have no time to learn it now. Because I have to submit my project this week. So I thought someone here can provide me some help.

Comment: if you don't know anything about AJAX then maybe you should start reading and learning it. The fact that you have to submit your project this week is not our problem. You should have asked this question much earlier rather than waiting the last deadline. Nobody on Stack Overflow is going to do the work for you.

Comment: I want an example or some tutorial OK, not the actual code. I want just a hint.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7910/discussion-between-aishwarya-shiva-pareek-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: trying googling for `Ajax`. You will find lots of tutorials.